# How to retrieve the value of an input contained in another form on symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

in my controller i have this code :

```
$destinataires = [];
        $destinataires[]= $emailclient;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
        {
            $email = $request->request->get('emailclient'.$i);
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $destinataires[] = $email;
            }
        }
```

It works when I use it for input included in the form (twig):

```
{{ form_start(formUpload, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'batsendform', 'multipart' : true } }) }}
                    {{ form_row(formUpload.filepreview) }}<p id="batupload">Glissez le BAT 3D PDF ici.</p>

<div style="text-align: center;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#emailmodal">
        Ajouter des destinataires
    </button></div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="emailmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="color: black">Ajouter des emails destinataires du BAT</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <label style="color: black" for="emailclient1">Email 1 </label><input size="60" class="emailinput" type="email" name="emailclient1"> <br>
                <label style="color: black" for="emailclient2">Email 2 </label><input size="60" class="emailinput" type="email" name="emailclient2"> <br>
                <label style="color: black" for="emailclient3">Email 3 </label><input size="60" class="emailinput" type="email" name="emailclient3"> <br>
                <label style="color: black" for="emailclient4">Email 4 </label><input size="60" class="emailinput" type="email" name="emailclient4"> <br>
                <label style="color: black" for="emailclient5">Email 5 </label><input size="60" class="emailinput" type="email" name="emailclient5">

{{ form_end(formUpload) }}
```

But I want to use these values ​​from an external form (twig):

```
...
{{ form_start(formRefus) }}
   <label style="text-align: center;color: red;">Laisser des précisions au client. (Optionnel)</label>
   <textarea rows = "3" cols = "70" name = "messagegr"></textarea>
   {{ form_row(formRefus.submit) }}

{{ form_end(formRefus) }}
```

With the same method in my controller:

```
$formRefus = $this->createForm(RefusClientType::class);
                $formRefus->handleRequest($request);

if ($formRefus->isSubmitted() && $formRefus->isValid())
{
   $destinataires = [];
        $destinataires[]= $emailclient;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
        {
            $email = $request->request->get('emailclient'.$i);
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $destinataires[] = $email;
            }
        }
}
```

But this time the returned value is zero.
Does anyone have a method to work around this problem ? Thanks :)

Comment: check where controller return output

Comment: Symfony forms have their own input naming convention. Take a look at the generated html to see what they do. In any event, if you are using the form system then you should not be pulling data directly from the request. And does RefusClientType have a collection of email forms? If not then that is something else that needs to be adjusted. Probably best to just work through some of the examples.

Comment: Ok thanks i get values with id, sorry :)